# Switch to current home user directory after switching user in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, user-accounts

I created a new user on my Linux machine with the following commands

```
sudo useradd -m foo.bar
sudo passwd foo.bar
```

After that, I switch to `foo.bar`, but the current directory does not direct to the current user and the info of the current user does not show in the command line

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-47-200:~$ su foo.bar
Password:
$
$ whoami
foo.bar
$
$ pwd
/home/ubuntu
```

I would like to have something like

```
foo.bar@ip-172-31-47-200:~$
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you _really_ need to have a dot in the user name?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: it does not matter.

Comment: I believe default `NAME_REGEX` in Ubuntu is `^[a-z][-a-z0-9]*$` (Starting with a lowercase letter then any number of dashes, lowercase letters or digits. No `_, @ or ..`also in Debian having dots in the user name creates some issues with scripts using `chown`,

Comment: @MichaelHarvey thanks for your suggestion. I've tried a different username like `foobaz`, but this does not help. I still got the aforementioned issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you're looking for is the flag '-l'. You can directly access a users home-directory + initialize path-variables etc. by using "su -l user", where user is the username you're logging in with.

More information: [su man-page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html)

Comment: thanks! it works. But why can I access directly to some users, for example, `ubuntu` by using `su ubuntu` without `-l`?

Comment: That is somewhat dependent on your distro/installation/user configuration. Citing from the link above (-l):

Start the shell as a login shell with an environment similar to a real login: 
-initializes the environment variables HOME, SHELL, USER, LOGNAME, and PATH
-changes to the target user’s home directory
-sets argv[0] of the shell to '-' in order to make the shell a login shell

So -l is the usual way to do it to circumvent issues with the environment when changing the user. For some "provided" users it's as simple as having that flag set automatically. Recommended: su -l ubuntu ;)

Comment: you can also use the short version `su -` instead of `su -l`, like: `su - foo.bar`